# does not implement inherited abstract member

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I'm moving a project from c# for desktop, .net framework v4.5 to Windows Phone 8. However I am now getting this error and two similar ones.

'`Downloader.Convertors.PaginatedListConvertor<T>`' does not implement inherited abstract member '`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter.ReadJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader, System.Type, object, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer)`'

What is going wrong?

Comment: It would be useful to see some more code. Perhaps the class you've implemented which should be implementing the abstract function?

Comment: I agree with Nathan.  I was able to answer your question, but going forward, you won't get very many responses to your questions if you don't provide details of your issue.  Here is the source code for JSON.NET if you need to see other method signatures.  https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json ... you will run into similar issues with WriteJson and others from the upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I'd hazard a guess that somewhere in the NewtonSoft code, there's a directive like this:

```
#if NET40
// an implementation of those methods
#endif
```

Not sure how you'd fix it, other than:

- see if they have a windows phone 8 version
- implement the missing methods

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to mark `Downloader.Convertors.PaginatedListConvertor<T>` as abstract if you don't want to implement some methods in this class.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter list in that particular error represent the parameters you should have in your override method.  You probably have a discrepancy with your override method code.

You probably upgraded your referenced DLL from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.0 (or .NET 4.5).  Because the signature of the method changed, you need to update your parameter list in your override method.  When doing this, always look at the executive summary for the upgrade, or look at any specific source code being used in a referenced DLL if your referenced DLL changes.  .NET Reflections is a nice tool for this activity.  It can reverse engineer the DLL you are referencing, so you can look at the source code.  In your case, they provide the source code.  http://json.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#readme.txt

original:

```
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

new:

```
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object obj, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```